# How to position an absolute element in the specific coordinates of the body with a relative position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an element that I'm checking the click event for it. and when it clicked I want to add a div element based on the coordinates of the event.The code is here:

```
$('.quick-popup-icon').click(function (e) {

  var popup = document.createElement("div")
  popup.style.top = e.pageY + "px"
  popup.style.marginLeft = e.pageX  + "px"
  popup.style.position = "absolute"

  document.body.append(popup)
}
```

When the body position isn't relative it's working fine and the element is adding in the exact coordinates. But when our body has a relative position and we need to scroll everything falls apart. And because our application is a Chrome extension I can't change the position of the body.
Here is my question specifically: How can I append an element with the absolute position in a document with the relative position with getting the event coordinates.

Comment: Do you have the option of making the pop up `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: @isaacsan123 Yes! It doesn't work. actually with adding fixed position the div doesn't appear.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's a z-index issue.  Try adding something like `z-index: 9000;` just to test it out.

Comment: @isaacsan123 It doesn't work. I can't see the added div.

Comment: Could you post some a snippet of the code to demonstrate the error?  Would be easier to pinpoint what's not working, because in the following example, everything seems to be working fine, unless there is some other functionality you want the code to do that I'm not aware of: https://codepen.io/isaac-svi/pen/dyREYQj

Comment: @isaacsan123 Thanks for sharing the code with me. Defining fixed position with e.clientY is working fine. But as I said This is a chrome extension and I wanna add some div into the DOM. If position is fixed, it stays fixed by scrolling on the page and this is not good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237761/discussion-between-isaacsan-123-and-haniyeh-asemi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why everything falls apart when the body is `position: relative;` is that an absolute element inside of a relative or absolute positioned parent element is affected by the position of the parent element.

For example, if you have a relative div 200px from the left of the body and 500px from the top of the body, and you have an absolute div inside of that relative div with `top: 0;` and `left: 0`, the absolute div will by 0px from the top and left of the **parent div**.  Here's an example:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

However, in the same case, if we were to make the child have a position of fixed, top:0 and left:0 would make it go to the top-left corner of the page.

Example:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.child {
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /* just changed this line */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Basically, just make your pop up `position: fixed`.

---

**EDIT**
If you can't see the div, adding a z-index to the fixed element can help.

Comment: It works fine when the parent is at the top of the page, put it in the middle of page with a scrollbar in Y coordniates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this. **Best of luck**.

```js
 $(function () {
      $('.quick-popup-icon').click(function (e) {
        var popup = document.createElement("div")
        popup.style.top = e.pageY + "px"
        popup.style.left= e.pageX + "px"
        popup.style.position = "absolute"
        popup.style.background="red"
        popup.style.width="50px"
        popup.style.height="50px"

       document.body.append(popup)
    })
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="position: relative;">
  <div style="background:#228877">
    <span style=" display:block;width: 100%;height: 200px" class="quick-popup-icon"></span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

let me know if something doesn't working as you want so we can solve this together. explaination at code desc.

```js
$('.quick-popup-icon').click(function (e) {
  
  const pY = $(this).offset().top, pX = $(this).offset().left;
  
  $('<div></div>')
  .css({
    'top' : (e.clientY - pY ) + "px",
    'left' : (e.clientX - pX )  + "px"
  })
  .appendTo( $('body') );

});

  // The .offset() method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element (specifically its border box, which excludes margins) relative to the document.
  
  // The clientX property returns the coordinate (according to the client area) of the mouse pointer
  
  // A demonstration of the differences between clientX and clientY and screenX and screenY: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_mouse_screenxy_clientxy
```

```css
body{
  position:relative;
}
body>span{
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  background:gray;
  width:50%;
  min-height:100px;
}
body>div{
  position:absolute;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background:red;
  z-index:1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="quick-popup-icon"></span>
```

Comment: I'm getting a negative value with running e.clientY - pY, You should consider a scroll for Y coordinates.